# Printing in virtualbox guest

Tags: virtualbox, printing

I have host Ubuntu 16.04 and guest windows 10. I am setting a USB printer. Now it can print in the host, but appears as "offline" in the guest. If I set the USB port accessible in the guest, then I can print in the guest but not in the host.

How to set the printer to be accessible in both the host and the guest?

Comment: The best way is probably to share it via the network from the host to the guest. Not sure how to do that, since I don't have a working printer.

Answer (score 1):

To enable printing from both the host Ubuntu and the guest Windows your best choice is to share that printer via your network (which then would be the internal network *localhost* between the host and the guest).

1. Make sure that printer sharing was enabled

   [image]
2. Search for printers in the Windows settings. Click on *The printer I want isn't listed*:

   [image]
3. Tick *select a shared printer* to give in the network name directly or **Browse** to find the network your printer is attached to:

   [image]
4. Select the appropriate network printer:

   [image]
5. Windows may need additional drivers for printing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But it doesn't work. I've shared the printer in host Ubuntu, but can't see any network printer in guest Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

In VirtualBox, by default, your VM is attached to a NAT (Network Address Translator) network, which in essence makes a LAN for all your VMs.  One easy way to be able to discover the printer in your LAN is by setting up the network adapter to use *Bridge Networking*.  You can access that setting under `Devices > Network > Network Settings`.

You can find more info about those networking terms [in this Oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/scoter/networking-in-virtualbox-v2)